# JAVA_HOME, MAVEN_HOME and PATH variables are not echoing though path is set in Windows machine

Tags: java, maven, path

I am using Windows Server 2012 R2. I Have set JAVA_HOME, MAVEN_HOME and updated the same in PATH variable too with "bin" folder. I am able to execute java and mvn command. But when I echo JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME, it does not echo anything back. 
Because of this problem my build is failing in TFS and none of the system and user defined variables are recognised in the build (this windows machine is used as build machine in TFS)

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80
MAVEN_HOME and M2_HOME = C:\apache-maven-3.3.2

Following are set in "computer"->right click->"properties"->"new variable" and added there. Updated PATH variable also in similar manner.

PS C:\Users\raji echo $JAVA_HOME
PS C:\Users\raji

PS C:\Users\raji echo $MAVEN_HOME
PS C:\Users\raji

PS C:\Users\raji echo $M2_HOME
PS C:\Users\raji

PS C:\Users\raji echo %JAVA_HOME%
PS C:\Users\raji %JAVA_HOME%

but java -version and mvn -version are working. How do I fix this?

Comment: Go with a machine restart.

Comment: You are using powershell rather than the command prompt. Try `echo $ENV:JAVA_HOME`

Comment: echo $ENV:JAVA_HOME works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following command in **PowerShell**:

Get-ChildItem Env:JAVA_HOME

Edit: if you only want the path you can use:

echo $env:JAVA_HOME

Comment: You should probably indicate that these are the commands for Powershell rather than windows cmd.

Comment: echo $ENV:JAVA_HOME   and also Get-ChildItem Env:JAVA_HOME works. So this means that path is correctly set for these. But when I run in TFS 2015 for maven, it throws me error that mvn command is not recognised.

I can see following through poweshell plugin console:
C:\apache-maven-3.3.9
while checking for MAVEN_HOME

Comment: I am able to run "mvn -version" command in the server. But when I run the same command in TFS using "inline powershell" plugin, then it throws me error that mvn command is not recognised. ANd when I give the full path of maven "C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\mvn -version", it does not give me any output in powershell plugin console

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting your tfs build agent service ( from services ), so that it will get the fresh environment variables.